# is Force View Controller Orientation working in iOS 16 beta

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiinterfaceorientation, ios16

According to the iOS & iPadOS 16 Beta 3 Release Notes:- Attempting to set an orientation on [UIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice) via `setValue:forKey:` isn’t supported and no longer works. Instead, they say use: preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation.

In my case, force view controller orientation is not working in iOS 16 beta either by using `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` or `requestGeometryUpdate`.

Previously, `UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")` was working fine.

Comment: Having same situation as you :( On iOS & iPadOS 16 Beta 4, it said "FIXED" but I tested and still the same, and console still display error message: [Orientation] BUG IN CLIENT OF UIKIT: Setting UIDevice.orientation is not supported. Please use UIWindowScene.requestGeometryUpdate(_:)

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73727291/ios16-present-uiviewcontroller-in-landscape-only-for-single-screen-not-working/73742232 man of the stack overflow  who can do the job can help here please.! Help awaited.

Comment: May be helpful for you, refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76329324/3887987

Answer (score 16):

It works for me.

In AppDelegate,

```
var orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return orientation
}
```

In view controller,

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.orientation = .landscapeRight
                    
let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .landscapeRight))

UIApplication.navigationTopViewController()?.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
```

In Helper,

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func navigationTopViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        let nav = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
        return  nav?.topViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: updated the answer. I added my helper here.

Comment: I confirm that this solution is working and helped me with my problem.

Comment: i confirm , this is working.

Comment: @J.Y.527 Would you mind me giving the equivalent C# code (for Xamarin/ MAUI) as an edit ?

Comment: @J.Y.527 how would i get this to work from a swiftUI view?

Comment: It's working for me. My problem was in AppDelegate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

My problem with my code below is that I'm trying to do it when closing a modal view and the view under it are not updated quick enough. If I put the requestGeometryUpdate on a separate button then when I close the view it work.

```
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {

    let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene

    windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .portrait))

}
```

Comment: Having exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

**It works for me:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    
    func setDeviceOrientation(orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
            windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: orientation))
        } else {
            UIDevice.current.setValue(orientation.toUIInterfaceOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        }
    }
}

extension UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    var toUIInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        switch self {
        case .portrait:
            return UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            return UIInterfaceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown
        case .landscapeRight:
            return UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight
        case .landscapeLeft:
            return UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft
        default:
            return UIInterfaceOrientation.unknown
        }
    }
}
```

**How to use it?**

Just call it on your UIViewController:

```
setDeviceOrientation(orientation: .landscapeRight)
```

**EDIT**

**More completed solution:**

```
import UIKit

final class DeviceOrientation {
    
    static let shared: DeviceOrientation = DeviceOrientation()
    
    // MARK: - Private methods
    
    private var windowScene: UIWindowScene? {
        return UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    }
    
    // MARK: - Public methods
    
    func set(orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: orientation))
        } else {
            UIDevice.current.setValue(orientation.toUIInterfaceOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        }
    }
    
    var isLandscape: Bool {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            return windowScene?.interfaceOrientation.isLandscape ?? false
        }
        return UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape
    }
    
    var isPortrait: Bool {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            return windowScene?.interfaceOrientation.isPortrait ?? false
        }
        return UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
    }
    
    var isFlat: Bool {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            return false
        }
        return UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat
    }
}

extension UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    var toUIInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        switch self {
        case .portrait:
            return UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            return UIInterfaceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown
        case .landscapeRight:
            return UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight
        case .landscapeLeft:
            return UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft
        default:
            return UIInterfaceOrientation.unknown
        }
    }
}
```

**How to use it:**

```
 DeviceOrientation.shared.set(orientation: .portrait)
```

Comment: Did you check ios 16.1?

Comment: Yes, it works. Do you have problems?

Comment: Are you applying supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor in AppDelegate? What orientations do you have checked in the Target's deployment info? Do you by any chance have a sample project we could check? Thanks.

Comment: I've set all orientations on supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor and this did not work to force the orientation..

Answer (score 3):

I tried all above solutions seem they're not 100% percent working. After through this post
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707735 i got the hint. Let's try this below code. It’s worked for me.

```
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
                
            let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
                windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: orientation)) { error in
                print(error)
                print(windowScene?.effectiveGeometry)
            }
               navigationController?.topViewController?.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed my issue seems like resolved by calling method below:

[UIViewController setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterface

You may give it a try.

Comment: Where do you call this? Mine doesn't work with this if I place it in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Does not work for me

Comment: Same here, not works. Any hack? iOS 16 feels terrible. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`setValue:forKey` is a method of old `NSObject` (`NSKeyValueCoding`). It's not  official documented and supported by `UIDevice` class. Using it is considering using a private api. Apple can terminate it anytime they want.

Answer (score 0):

Apple released new API which is replaced with setValue:forKey:"orientation".
[Apple update](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/3975944-requestgeometryupdate/)

```
guard let windowScene = view.window?.windowScene else { return }
windowScene.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .landscape)) { error in
// Handle denial of request.
}
```

But I am having problem about `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification` , it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Following Apple's documentation you need to

> Requests an update to the window scene’s geometry using the specified geometry preferences object.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/3975944-requestgeometryupdate/

So using the code in the example, you can change the way we set the orientation in our views using `requestGeometryUpdate` and using as well `setNeedsUpdateOFSupportedInterface`

```
public extension UIViewController {

func deviceOrientation(orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
        else { return }
        windowScene.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: orientation))
        self.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    }
  }
}
```