# iOS16+ Present UIViewController in landscape only for single screen not working [Swift 5.7]

Tags: swift, xcode, ios16, xcode14, swift5.7

Before iOS 16 presenting a single screen in landscape is fine for portrait application. The working code is as below.

**Remark**: *Whole application is in Portrait mode only.*

```
override public var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override public var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .landscapeLeft
}

override public var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .landscapeLeft
}
```

I found the solution but it's for [UIWindowScene](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/3975944-requestgeometryupdate) but **I need solution in UIWindow.** I need help to fix it in iOS 16.

Xcode - 14.0,
iOS - 16.0,
Simulator - 14 Pro

I can prepare demo if anyone needs.

Comment: Did you succeed to have it working for UIWindowScene? I'm getting an error the requested orientation is not supported

Comment: @Gutty1 I'm working with UIWindow only. So sorry that I've never tried with UIScene.

Comment: It's extremely tricky to do this well, and there's no easy solution.

Comment: @Fattie you can refer my answer. (Suggest if you get more idea)

Comment: May be helpful for you, refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76329324/3887987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many tries I came up with the simple solution. As I mentioned in the question my whole app is in portrait mode only and only one screen that I want to present in the landscape.

**This code doesn't required any external window to be `makeKeyAndVisible`.**
If you use extra window to present then you need to write to dismiss separately for iOS 16.

Old code which was working in previous versions of iOS 16 will be remain same and no change in it.

Magic lines are as below.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let _ = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController as? LandscapeChartVC {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            return .landscapeLeft
        } else {
            return .portrait
        }
    } else {
        return .portrait
    }
}
```

I've identified my landscape view controller in the appDelegate's `supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor`.

Well you can change word `presentedViewController` to get your controller. And that's it.

**Add support with iPad for all 3 or 4 orientation with this:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.IS_IPAD {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        if let _ = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController as? LandscapeChartVC {
            if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                return .landscapeLeft
            } else {
                return .portrait
            }
        } else {
            return .portrait
        }
    }
```

If requirement for iPad app to lock the orientations you can follow iPhone / above code.

This idea come up with answers and thank you everyone who shared interest. If anyone still get more improved solution I'll happy to update.

Comment: Awesome, this worked for me. I was trying to do the same but for a video player in full screen. In my case I had to add the following to your function in AppDelegate: `if ((window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("AVFullScreenViewController")!)) != nil)`

Comment: It finally didn't work for me as "AVFullScreenViewController" seems to be used by google ads and google login as well, so if I use this code it will rotate those two views too.

Answer (score 5):

this can be done in two ways.

1 .personally I prefer this way

**1.1 keep this function in AppDelegate to handle the orientation(this is must)**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .all
}
```

**1.2 in which ViewController you want the force orientation, go to that view controller and add these lines in the variable declaring section**

```
var forceLandscape: Bool = false

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
           forceLandscape ? .landscape : .portrait
}
```

we will be updating the **forceLandscape** so it will get updated, then the **supportedInterfaceOrientations** also will get updated

**1.3 Here we are setting the trigger for updating the forceLandscape (we can add these lines of code inside button action for handling IOS 16 force roatation)**

```
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            self.forceLandscape = true
            guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else { return }
            self.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2, execute: {
                windowScene.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .landscapeRight)){
                        error in
                        print(error)
                        print(windowScene.effectiveGeometry)
                }
            })
```

this will update the **forceLandscape**, so it will check the orientation and update according to it

**Above lines of code is for one way, another way is given below**

**2. Another way is updating orientation in AppDelegate class:**

**2.1 keep this function and property in AppDelegate to handle the orientation(this is must)**

```
var orientation : UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
            return orientation
        }
```

**2.2 In the viewcontroller button action we can update the propperty**

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDel.orientation = .landscape

        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
                self.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
                self.navigationController?.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
                windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .landscape)) { error in
                    print(error)
                    print(windowScene?.effectiveGeometry ?? "")
                }
            }
        }else{
            UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        }
```

Comment: Any idea how to get this working for one specific screen that is made using swiftUI?

Answer (score 1):

I found some related things in iOS 16 Release Notes.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-16-release-notes?changes=lat__8_1
There are some deprecations in UIKit:

> **Deprecations**
> [UIViewController shouldAutorotate] has been deprecated is no longer supported. [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation] has been deprecated and replaced with [UIViewController setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations].
> **Workaround**: Apps relying on shouldAutorotate should reflect their preferences using the view controllers supportedInterfaceOrientations. If the supported orientations change, use `-[UIViewController setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterface

I think you may have to use **setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterface**.

Comment: I already tried this, and is not working...

Comment: No, this is really not working.

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround for presenting modal view controller from portrait in landscape I managed to come up with is combination of `setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()`, `requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .landscape))` and allowed interface orientation on AppDelegate on **a new window**.

#### AppDelegate:

```swift
var allowedOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .allButUpsideDown

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return allowedOrientation
}
```

#### Presenting view controller in landscape

```swift
var overlayWindow: UIWindow? // New window to present the controller in
…

func presentModalInLandscape(vc: ViewController) {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.allowedOrientation = .landscapeRight

        if let currentWindowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
            overlayWindow = UIWindow(windowScene: currentWindowScene)
        }

        overlayWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert
        overlayWindow?.rootViewController = livevc

        overlayWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        // It's important to do it after the interface has enough time to rotate
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
           self.overlayWindow?.windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .landscapeRight))
           vc.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
        }

    } else {
        // For iOS 15 it's enough to present it modally
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Then when you want to dismiss it you need to

```swift
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    self.overlayWindow?.isHidden = true // Destroy the window
    self.overlayWindow?.windowScene = nil
    self.overlayWindow = nil 
    appDelegate().allowedOrientation = .allButUpsideDown // Reset allowed orientation
    self.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations() // Set the controller back
} else {
    self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

It's still not 100% because the view controller is presented in landscape, then flicks back to portrait, and then again rotates to landscape after a second. But without the UIWindow it sometimes does this 2x before it locks in the landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewController` I want to lock is inside a `UINaviationController`. For this scenario here's my working solution

I have this `struct` which has a `lock` and `unlock` method.

```swift
struct AppOrientation {
    
    // statusBarOrientation
    // 0 - unknown
    // 1 - portrait
    // 2 - portraitUpsideDown
    // 3 - landscapeLeft
    // 4 - landscapeRight
    
    
    static let ORIENTATION_KEY: String = "orientation"
    
    private static func lockInterfaceOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
        
        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            delegate.orientationLock = orientation
        }
    }
        
//    Important
//    Notice that UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight is assigned to UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft
//    and UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft is assigned to UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.
//    The reason for this is that rotating the device requires rotating the content in the opposite direction.
    
    // Note that UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft is equal to UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight (and vice versa).
    // This is because rotating the device to the left requires rotating the content to the right.
    
    // DevieOrientation
    // 0 - unknown
    // 1 - portrait
    // 2 - portraitUpsideDown
    // 3 - landscapeLeft
    // 4 - landscapeRight
    // 5 - faceUp
    // 6 - faceDown
    
    // UIInterfaceOrientation
    // - landscapeLeft:
    // -- Home button on the left
    // - landscapeRight:
    // -- Home button on the right
    
    // UIDevice orientation
    // - landscapeLeft:
    // -- home button on the right
    // - landscapeRight:
    // -- home button on the left
    
    static func lockDeviceToLandscapeLeft() {
        
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
            
            if let controller = windowScene?.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? RMNavigationController {
                controller.lockLandscape = true
            }
        } else {
            UIDevice.current.setValue(UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: ORIENTATION_KEY)
            lockInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeRight)
        }
        

        
        // the docs say you should call 'attemptRorationToDeviceOrientation()
        // lots of StackOverflow answers don't use it,
        // but a couple say you _must_ call it.
        // for me, not calling it seems to work...
//        UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
    }
    
    static func unlockOrientation() {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
            
            if let controller = windowScene?.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? RMNavigationController {
                controller.lockLandscape = false
            }
        } else {
            lockInterfaceOrientation(.all)
        }
    }
}
```

Prior to ios16 you only needed to call these two methods.

As of ios16 you now need to call `setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()` as well

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  AppOrientation.lockDeviceToLandscapeLeft()
        
  if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    self.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
  } else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
  }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    AppOrientation.unlockOrientation()
}
```